# How to send an embed when bot enters Discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I look for the embed of the code that I have passed to be sent in the first available channel every time the bot enters a server.

This would be the code snippet.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntent`your text`Bits, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

const prefix = config.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot Ready');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
});


client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'));
    if (channel) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0xF99CF8)
            .setTitle('**B**')
            .setAuthor('S')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/N4')
            .setDescription('H') 
        channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

As a result of this code, the bot does not send any type of message when entering servers, but starts normally.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: Discord.js v14.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using discord.js v14 then you will need to update your way in replying with Embeds

Just change to this code:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'));
  if (channel) {
    const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(0xF99CF8)
      .setTitle('**B**')
      .setAuthor('S')
      .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/N4')
      .setDescription('H') 
    channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
  }
});
```

Also you will need to edit the first line to:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
```

just remove the third line to make your code cleaner

For more details you can go here :
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

Comment: the channel type is a number not a string.

Answer (score 0):

In [`discord.js` v14](https://old.discordjs.dev/),

- **MessageEmbed** was renamed to **EmbedBuilder** along with other classes.
- Channel types need to be checked via `enum`s.
- `<Guild>.me` was replaced by `<Guild>.members.me`.
- Permission flags now follow **PascalCase**.

```js
const {
    ChannelType,
    Client,
    EmbedBuilder,
    GatewayIntentBits
} = require('discord.js');

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText && channel.permissionsFor(guild.members.me).has('SendMessages'));
    if (channel) {
        const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0xF99CF8)
            .setTitle('**B**')
            .setAuthor('S')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/N4')
            .setDescription('H')
        channel.send({
            embeds: [exampleEmbed]
        });
    }
});
```

Read more about breaking changes in `v14` [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html).